# How to check if a Hyper-V machine is Windows or Linux?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, hyper-v

I'm building a table with information about Hyper-V machines that I have on my PC.

I got most information from Powershell commands, namely using

```
Get-VM | Where {$_.Id –eq '" + vm["Name"].ToString() + "'} | fl *
```

and `Msvm_ComputerSystem` queries.

I can get my own operating system using

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Format-List Caption
```

but how can I get the Hyper-V virtual machine operating system (it would suffice to know if it's Windows or Linux)?

**Update**

I've tried installing different Windows and Linux distributions (XP, Vista, Debian, Mint and Sparky), then went to check the Hyper-V VMCX file looking for some kind of pattern in them, but couldn't find any either. Besides it's pretty hard to scan through all that "gibberish" on notepad. It does have a bunch of information and maybe it's somewhere hidden in there, does anyone know how to properly read these files? Could be a way to solve the problem.

Comment: Does Hyper-V know if a VM is Windows or Linux? I don't have an install to hand to play with, but I can't see an option skimming docs, nor can I find the string 'Linux' in some old VM config files I have to hand. I do remember VMWare asks you what OS you're putting on a VM, and that affects the set of virtual devices at least, but does Hyper-V do the same?

Comment: I don't think Hyper-V has that, VirtualBox also asks you at first what the operating system is and it's visible on the list, but Hyper-V doesn't, and doesn't seem to have any property in the settings that shows it either, that's why I don't know where to get it/look for it.

Comment: I'd check the hardware device lists for Windows and Linux VMs to see if there's anything obviously different there you could use - I'd guess PowerShell can enumerate the virtual hardware in a VM? Apart from that, if the VMs are up you could try pinging them and checking the TTL value (Windows always used to use 64 for direct ping, Linux 256), or if you can read the first sector of the VHDX you can inspect the partition table and see what partition type(s) you have, which will vary between Linux and Windows.

Comment: I can't even ping because I don't really know how to work with the network adapters on Hyper-V. VirtualBox is so much easier to work with, but sadly I have to get these features available only for Hyper-V machines.